# finding number of repeated users who have interacted with a category

Tags: mysql, hive

I am new to sql and am trying to figure out the following..
Imagine the following table:

```
user_id, category_id
1, 12344
1, 12344
1, 12345
2, 12345
2, 12345
3, 12344
3, 12344
```

and so on..
I want to find number of repeated users each category got..

so, in example above..

```
12344, 2 (because user_id 1 and 3 are repeated users)
12345, 1 (user_id 2 is repeated user.. 1 is not as that user visited just once)
```

How do i figure this out in sql/hive?

Comment: You really need a PRIMARY KEY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

E.g.:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,user_id INT NOT NULL
,category_id INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table (user_id,category_id) VALUES
(1, 12344),
(1, 12344),
(1, 12345),
(2, 12345),
(2, 12345),
(3, 12344),
(3, 12344);

SELECT category_id
     , COUNT(*) total 
  FROM 
     ( SELECT x.* 
         FROM my_table x 
         JOIN my_table y 
           ON y.user_id = x.user_id 
          AND y.category_id = x.category_id 
          AND y.id < x.id
     ) a 
 GROUP 
    BY category_id;
+-------------+-------+
| category_id | total |
+-------------+-------+
|       12344 |     2 |
|       12345 |     1 |
+-------------+-------+
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a little hard to follow what you're looking for, but test this:

```
select category_id, count(user_id) from (Select category_id, user_id, count(table_primary_id) as 'total' from tablename group by category_id, user_id) a where total > 1 group by category_id
```

The subquery counts the number of times a user visited a category, and the outside query should count the number of users who visited a category more than once.